# Are hardware RAID systems with silent corruption protection available?

Tags: storage

I know ZFS has protection against silent corruption, but I'm building a Windows server. Are there options out there for adding local, silent-corruption-protected storage to a Windows server, or is ZFS-over-network the only option?

I would like to pay extra for something that can compute the checksums fast enough to make the hard drive the bottleneck. Are such I/O cards available?

Comment: There is a standard for this: "T10 PI." With my limited google searches I only found a Linux / SAN-based implementation at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/silent-data-corruption-1911480.html

Answer (score 6):

Currently only ZFS (and soon BTRFS) have chechsumming of all I/O operations. NTFS does checksumming on journal writes, as do many linux filesystems.

The higher end RAID cards also do block level validations in the background. It isn't filesystem aware but it is sufficient to suss out bad clusters and relocate data proactively. The point of ZFS systems is to *avoid* such hardware based checksumming systems, but RAID cards have been doing this validation for many years now.

The hardware solutions we have now provide silent corruption protection from the storage controller down to the actual media. ZFS extends that protection to the filesystem layer in the kernel and when used in isolation of modern hardware solutions can protect the whole stack. If you want that kind of protection for Windows, you won't get it; you'll have to rely on hardware solutions and take your chances with the storage-card to application transmission path.

Using a ZFS filer doesn't get you any additional protection vs NTFS+hardware either. You still have the NIC to application route unprotected in the Windows server, which is the same vulnerability as the storage-card to the app in the hardware solution. The only reason a ZFS-filer would be beneficial would be if you don't *have* the right hardware and are relying on ZFS to do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Do those higher-end RAID cards you mention rely on secondary signs, like slow reads of specific clusters, or do they actually checksum the data?

Comment: @romkyns They read the data, and if it works it passes. If there are troubles, it deals with it. For data in parity or mirrored setups, it's compared vs the parity-bits or the mirrored block. RAID5/6 actually is checksumming everything, that's where the parity blocks come from.

Comment: Then this isn't what I'm looking for. I believe a traditional RAID5 controller does not do enough checksumming to protect against silent data corruption. It will notice that the parity is wrong, but in order to recover, it needs to know which of the drives messed up (I think) - which is by definition impossible in the case of a _silent_ data corruption.

Comment: @romkyns RAID5 *is* exactly what you're looking for. When a write comes to a R5 drive-set, the controller computes the parity value and writes both the original and the parity information. During the validation sweep, if the written-block doesn't match the parity information it knows corruption has happened and can deal with it using the parity information already stored.

Comment: The RAID5 algorithm, simplified, spreads two bits of data onto three drives by saving `bit1` to `drive1`, `bit2` to `drive2`, and `bit1^bit2` to `drive3`. If I told you I toggled one of these three bits, but didn't tell you which one, how would you recover the original two bits with certainty? `1 1 1` has the wrong parity, but was the original data `1 0 1`, `0 1 1`, or `1 1 0`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, as Mark Wagner pointed out in the comment, T10-PI can be used for that. I know that LSI 9361-8i (Supermicro AOC-S3108L-H8iR) controller support it, but it's expensive. You need to format disks with sg_format (NOTE, if the process is interrupted the disk will not be accessible through the controller and you'll need to plug it directly into MB or other controller to reformat). I think majority of modern disks are T10-PI capable, please check specs of your disks. Note, T10-PI arrays are ~ 10% slower in some of my tests.
2. Note that (some?) NVMe drives also provide such capability, at least Intel P4610 Enterprise NVMe do. It's called end-to-end data protection in the Intel docs. On linux you can read `man nvme-format`.
3. As an option, you can install hypervisor such as Proxmox VE onto your server, and install Windows server as a guest VM. In this case you can use ZFS in Proxmox (which is fully supported) to protect your data.